# How to get Pylint to display code smells in coc.nvim ? (Refactor issues)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, lint, vim-plugin

I'm using [Coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) with [coc-pyright](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright) and as suggested in the documentation I edited my coc-settings.json to display :

```
{
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true
}
```

Despite all of that, whenever I write a "smelly" code, I don't get any notifications. (I do get errors if the code doesn't work, but nothing related to [refactoring](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_pylint)).

Exemple :

```
if foo > 1 and foo < 2:
    return bar
```

This is not flagged, when I should get : "[R1716 chained-comparison] : ["Simplify chained comparison between the operands"] was reported by Pylint."

The valid way being :

```
if 1 < foo < 2:
    return bar
```

Should I look into using a different plugin ?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker/dedicated support channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, coc-pyright runs Pylint with a limit rules that ignore the `chained-comparison`.

This has been fixed in latest coc-pyright, `:CocUpdate` to latest release and try again.